# How to set Object in array typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to create new array by json data But I have no idea to create Object!
for show to page(loop for)

my json data

```
"LIBRARIES":{
"LIBRARY":[
{
"status":"available",
"callNumber":"123456"
},
{
"status":"available",
"callNumber":"434356"
}
]
}
```

and

```
"search":{
"lsr02":[
"31011103618567",
"31011001644160"
]}
```

I want to create object to store this data

I want

```
"NEWDATA":{
"NEW":[
{
"status":"available",
"callNumber":"123456",
"lsr02": "31011103618567" ///set lsr02 to store in NEW
},
{
"status":"available",
"callNumber":"434356"
"lsr02":"31011001644160"
}
]
}
```

and I try

```
let details: string[] = [];
for (let x of this.item.LIBRARIES.LIBRARY){
      details.push(x);
  }
  for (let x of this.item.search.lsr02){
      details.push(x);
  }
  console.log(details)
```

> console.log(details) show

```
{
"status":"available",
"callNumber":"123456"
},
{
"status":"available",
"callNumber":"434356"
}
{
"31011103618567"
},
{
"31011001644160"
}
```

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing the search objects separately. You need to assign them to appropriate library object. Try this;

```js
this.item = {
  "LIBRARIES": {
    "LIBRARY": [{
        "status": "available",
        "callNumber": "123456"
      },
      {
        "status": "available",
        "callNumber": "434356"
      }
    ]
  },
  "search": {
    "lsr02": [
      "31011103618567",
      "31011001644160"
    ]
  }
}




let details = [];


for (let i = 0; i < this.item.LIBRARIES.LIBRARY.length; i++) {
  let lib = this.item.LIBRARIES.LIBRARY[i];
  lib.lsr02 = this.item.search.lsr02[i]
  details.push(lib);
}

console.log(details)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export class NEWDATA {
 public status:string;
 public callNumber:string;
 public lsr02 : string;

  constractor(_status : string, _callNumber : string, _lsr02 : string){
    this.status = _status;
    this.callNumber = _callNumber;
     this.lsr02 = _lsr02;
  }
}

details : Array<NEWDATA> = [];

for (let i = 0; i < this.item.LIBRARIES.LIBRARY.length; i++) {
  details.push(new NEWDATA(this.item.LIBRARIES.LIBRARY[i].status, this.item.LIBRARIES.LIBRARY[i].callNumber,  this.item.search.lsr02[i]));
}
```